# mongodb 32bit mmap() failed with multidatabases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mmap

I have a virtual machine where i am running my node.js app with mongo databases.
I know the 32Bit issue but i do not know, why this already happens on my system.

If i am running my testcases i create a db for each testsuite -> after a suite has finished i drop all collections, indexes, call db.dropDatabase and remove also db-files created in my dbpath.

But after a while i get this error (at the moment i would really reach the limit, if i would not delete db files) even if i do not reach the physically limit of 2gb.
After running mongo repair everything works again.

Did i miss something?
Maybe i have to run another mongo command to reinit mongod?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some more details? What version of MongoDB, what O/S, how big are your data files, and what are your command line options (`db.serverCmdLineOpts()` in the `mongo` shell)?

Comment: Okay more details: I am running the app on debian vm 32bit 2gb ram.
Each database has same models.

Comment: A testsuite only tests all methods on one model/collection.
I drop indexes with model.collection.dropAllIndexes and after that i remove the model with model.remove.
And after that i use db.dropDatabase to clear db files.

One testcase creates 4 databases and deletes them, yet.
One db has two files *****.ns (16mb), *****.0 (65mb).

During the creation of db number 32 mongo crashs with the 32bit storage limitation error.

But at that moment all other db files are removed.

After running the repair command and restarting mongo everything works.

Sry for 2 comments pressed accidently enter.

Comment: remove doesn't actually reclaim the space, but regardless of that, why do you need to unindex, and remove if you do dropDatabase?

Comment: Do not know^^ want to get save, to really delete everything.
But how do i can reclaim the space?

I remove all files... everything is clear in the dbfolder?

Comment: okay now i will reuse the first created testdb for all other tests... but the process with database repair is very impracticable if you want to create dbs with dynamic names and you want to delete/free disk space on the fly, because you will never use this dbname...

Maybe there is a solution for that?